# Log-normally distributed sum

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is it the case that the sum of 2 log-normally distributed random variables is also log-normally distributed?

If so, is the difference also log-normally distributed?

And if so, how is the possibly negative value reconciled? By taking the absolute value?

Thank you

Comment: No & No. Neither the sum nor the difference of log-normally distributed random variables is still log-normally distributed. Only a product of them / reciprocal / raise to a certain power does (these will become linear operations inside the exponent in which preserve the normality).

Comment: Do you have a proof or a link that shows that the sum is not log-normally distributed?

Comment: No idea what your motivation is. If this is a theoretical exercise, then you should follow @BGM's Comment.Misbehavior of differences is your 'proof'. // If a practical application, why not take logs so both are normal, then add or subtract, then do whatever analysis is appropriate (before or after returning to exponential scale). // In practice, sums and differences of lognormals are sometimes hardly distinguishable from lognormal. That is logs of sum or diff may be consistent with normality according to usual normality tests. Sometimes you get remarkable outliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment continued.** If you have a practical application in mind, you might try simulating
anticipated kinds of data for a preview of what difficulties might be in store. Whether or not you use R, maybe you can follow
my demo below.

The particular case shown (with data arising from a 'seed' based
on today's date) is one in which difficulties arise that
indicate non-normality. `NaN`s/`NA`s arise from negative differences (simply
*ignored* in normality test and plots).
Many simulations with unpredicted seeds encounter no such difficulties.

If totals and differences of lognormal data were lognormal, then their
logs $T$ and $D$ should be normal.

```
set.seed(2218)  # Remove this line for new simulation
x = exp(rnorm(50, 5,  05))  # Lognormal
y = exp(rnorm(50, 9,  1))   #  ... data
t = log(x + y);  d = log(y - x)  # totals and diffs
 Warning message:
 In log(y - x) : NaNs produced
shapiro.test(t); shapiro.test(d) # normality test

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  t 
W = 0.6793, p-value = 3.578e-09  # Spectacular rejection of normality for totals


        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  d 
W = 0.976, p-value = 0.5114      # IGNORING impossible values, consistent with normality

summary(t); summary(d)      # descriptive statistics
Totals   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
        7.594   8.666   9.325   9.885  10.520  21.940 
Diffs    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
        5.454   8.376   8.957   8.960   9.628  11.090       8 

# Graphs
par(mfrow=c(2,2))  # 2x2 array of four panels
boxplot(t, col="skyblue2", pch=20, main="Totals") # watch for outliers
 qqnorm(t, pch=20, main="Norm Q-Q: Totals")
boxplot(d, col="skyblue2", pch=20, main="Diffs") # normal probability plots
 qqnorm(d, pch=20, main="Norm Q-Q: Diffs")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]